# How do validate checkoutpage Review & Payments billing address form

Tags: shipping

[image]

I have no about this validation. And I can't find where this code coming from. Please give some ideas, How to validate this form

Comment: What you want to do?

Comment: I need to validate this page.

Comment: need to validate zipcode and phone number validation exact digit as 10 digits and 6 digits